# Upload new iOS 10 application built by older Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode8, appstore-approval

I've a simple question.
 What are requirements for new app upload to latest AppStore?
I mean is it required to use latest Xcode 8 and also latest swift or is it possible to upload the new application running on swift 2.2 version using Xcode 8 or maybe with Xcode 7?
 I'm curios if apple states informations like that somewhere.

Comment: You cannot upload app that supports ios 10 using xcode 7, because there are some methods and functionality change and the target ios version is only available till ios 9.x. So its better to use xcode 8.x and check deprecated methods.

Comment: So you mean created archive using xcode 7 isn't uploadable to latest app store? So then, is it possible to create archive using xcode 8 without swift 2.3 or swift 3 migration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  and/or the store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple recommends you to build and submit to App store with latest SDK. However, it doesn't mean that it forces you to do that. In other words, you can use older SDK to compile you source code. For example, you can compile you app with XCode8 with Swift 3, but if you do with XCode7 and Swift 2.2, it's also fine. 
Have a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1806/_index.html